# Replace lots of switches with polymorphism but no type code

Tags: refactoring, switch-statement, design-patterns

I have a class which could benefit with the state pattern. However the common "Replace Type Code with State/Strategy" refactoring does not seem to fit well in my case: the state is calculated by watching other objects, there is no type code variable.

Most of my class code is just "calculating" some state when it is called, and running the functions for that state.

Forcing a type code variable *feels* wrong because:

1. I will be forced to call an "updateState()" function in every place where the polymorphic functions are used.
2. My class will no longer be 100% behavior, which I would rather habe instead of some internal state.

Since the state must be calculated every single time its functions are called, I am wonder if I am thinking about the wrong pattern.

Normally I refactor this:

```
if (this.someOtherThingIsRunning()) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

like this:

```
typecode.doSomething()
// that being polymorphic
```

it seems strange doing:

```
updateTypeCode()
typecode.doSomething()
```

Does the state pattern applies to this case? Is there any alternative strategy pull from polymorphism without a type code?

Answer (score 0):

While writing my question, I realized that maybe I could just make the type code a function and return a temporal (function scope) type code. Like:

```
typecode().doSomething()
```

This solution would never store the state, which is what I want to avoid. However I am still wondering if my problem started because I am using the wrong pattern.

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to storing the state, maybe think about combining State and Observer to modify the state as the dependent classes change (rather than checking on every call). There's only certain models that this will work for though.

Otherwise you might as well say `object.doSomething()` and have the checks inside `doSomething()`. In this case using design patterns doesn't present any significant advantages (though if you loosen up slightly on the definitions of design patterns, many things would be considered such). I'd probably go with:

```
doSomething()
{
  if (someOtherThingIsRunning())
    doOneThing();
  else
    doAnotherThing();
}
```

The alternative (that you already suggested) is to have the above checks in `typecode()` and to return another class that contains the method `doSomething()`.

Comment: the reason I want to refactor is because I have 4 functions in my class branching with that very same conditional, that is the reason I wanted to spice up with polymorphism, even if I extract the methods. The foremost thing I would hate to do is storing the state if it is not necessary, hence I want to ignore the classic State pattern. My class only cares about the Observed class when certain functions are called. Changes in the values of the observed class are not important. Hence the Observer pattern also seems out of place.

Comment: The main reason I suggested State/Observer is for when the check is time consuming, then it might be faster to keep track of the changes rather than checking them each time (but I was thinking something more along the lines of selective notification, which is probably not pure Observer, and likely a bit hacky).

Comment: Having multiple functions with the same condition check does change things. Then your suggestion of `typecode().doSomething()` is probably best, or have the `doSomething()` function look like: `doSomething() { getState()->doSomethingHere(); }`.